# Fatal error detected by Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, fatal-error, javacv

I am facing a strange configuration issue, the application runs my fine on my laptop but the application crashes on another laptop during the deployment phase and it generates a dump file in the place where the application is located.

Here are the intial lines of the dump file:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION (0xe06d7363) at pc=0x7555b727, pid=1444, tid=4508
JRE version: 7.0-b147
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb727]
```

Here is the stack trace in the dump file:

```
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb727]  RaiseException+0x58
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x27819]  CxxThrowException+0x45

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvSetImageROI(Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$IplImage;Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$CvRect;)V+0
J  org.bytedeco.javacv.Blob.testDetect(Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$IplImage;IIIIILorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$CvRect;Ljava/lang/String;)[[I
J  com.omr.app.OmrModel.DetectUserIdQuizIdCircles()V
j  com.omr.app.OmrController$2.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Void;+315
j  com.omr.app.OmrController$2.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+29
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+46
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Comment: You're using an old version of JavaCV. Try to update to the latest version and try again.

Comment: @SamuelAudet I have now tested my application on five different systems but this issue only seems to be occurring in the field, seems very strange no?

Comment: There might be conflicting MSVC runtimes on those machines. Microsoft does release DLLs with the same name that are incompatible.

Comment: @SamuelAudet There is only one MSVC runtime that is currently visible in the control panel.

Comment: Right, so try to uninstall that and see.

Comment: @SamuelAudet There was initially no MSVC runtime installed, when I installed it, the crashes were resolved to some extent but they still are occurring from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

try this trouble shooting guide by oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/introduction.html

my guess is that there is a issue with the environment. try by installing jdk 8 on machine from which you are deploying.

Comment: try jstack or jmap to dig deep

Comment: The problem is originating in msvcr.dll no? Might be an issue with Microsoft redistributal package?

Comment: is your deployment machine 64 bit ?

Comment: take a look at this bug http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=f2d8b1936338c7b2f4fffa33b09f?bug_id=6900784

Comment: No i am not invoking the attach method explicitly and the machine is 32 bit.